# How to recognize line break in a database column's data?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

Can anyone advise what is the ideal approach to recognize line break in a database column's data?

Using `\r\n` or `chr(10)`? What is the difference actually?

Does C# code need to do any special handling to split the lines or it will be recognized automatically?

Comment: There is no difference. `\n` is a textual representation for `chr(10)`

Comment: @zerkms I think that \n is 13+10. REPLACE(@string, CHAR(13)+CHAR(10), '')

Comment: @Royi Namir: `\n` is ASCII 10, `\r` is ASCII 13

Comment: @zerkms confusing... but \n also go down 1 line and also  return the cursor to the left.... so i assumed it consists of both.

Comment: @Royi Namir: the behaviour depends on implementation, but they are two different characters with different semantics

Comment: @zerkms - There is a difference. `\r\n` means nothing to SQL Server it just stores it as the four individual characters. It only makes any difference to `C#` in string literals too. If you retrieve a string from SQL Server containing that sequence of characters it won't be treated as a line break automatically.

Comment: @Martin Smith: I don't see your point. I never said they are the same characters UPD: Oh, I see - my initial comment was to express there is no difference between `\n` and ASCII 10

Comment: Doesn't this question hinge on what control or tool is being used to display the data? Is this a textbox that needs to be set to multiline, or are we talking about some kind of query window? Is it WPF, Winforms?

Answer (score 3):

1. `\r` is `char(13)` known as the "Carriage Return" character.
2. `\n` is `char(10)` known as the "Line Feed" character.
3. `\r\n` is `char(13) + char(10)` i.e. case 1 & 2 are concatenated.

Different operating systems use different combinations when reading or writing new lines in text data, the most common are:

- Windows uses the combination in case 3, referred to as "Carriage Return Line Feed".
- Unix and Unix-like systems use case 2, just the "Line Feed".

In C# you can handle all 3 cases by splitting the lines like this:

```cs
string[] lines = dbText.Split(new string[] { "\r\n", "\n", "\r" },
                              StringSplitOptions.None);
```

Other characters and combinations are used by other operating systems and this subject even has it's own [Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline) with way more detail than you'll probably ever need!

Comment: Macs use just "\r", Mainframes (OS/390 - EBCDIC) use "\u0085", and some other systems use FormFeed = "\u000C". Please add these to your list and to the separator list string[] and I will +1 :).

Comment: @srutzky Thanks for the feedback. It seems different versions of Mac use different line endings. I added the final comment and wikipedia link anyway.

Comment: Ok, good on the link. Thanks. And after thinking more about it, the mainframe one doesn't matter as the entire character set would be different. I still think "\r" by itself should be in that separator array, but regardless, +1 as this answer is correct.